# using local fonts in drawing html5 canvas text

Tags: html, canvas

I'm trying to build a simple tool like meme generator using HTML5 canvas. Is it possible to use local fonts on the mobile phone (this is target towards mobile) in the canvas?

Answer (score 3):

@Akxe correctly answers that you can `.fillText` using local fonts to draw on html5 canvas.

It's also common to pull necessary font(s) from various internet font hosts.

Here's an example of how to download a web font & draw with it on html5 canvas:

```js
// load google font == Monoton
WebFontConfig = {
  google:{ families: ['Monoton'] },
  active: function(){start();},
};
(function(){
  var wf = document.createElement("script");
  wf.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.10/webfont.js';
  wf.async = 'true';
  document.head.appendChild(wf);
})();


var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

function start(){
  ctx.font = '40px Monoton';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
  ctx.fillText('Monoton    Font', 20, 10);
  var width=ctx.textMetrics('No').width;
  console.log(width);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>"Monoton" font drawn on canvas is a downloaded web font</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=100></canvas>
```

Comment: Why not  `active: start` no need to wrap it in function right?

Comment: @Akxe, Sure, that's fine. I usually wrap my init code in functions because I'm usually doing other tasks along with `start()`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify any font to the canvas. You should be able to type anything that CSS would accept

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "Arial 30px";
```