# Draw Threejs TextGeometry along the path

Tags: text, path, 3d, three.js, geometry

I have some model and want cover it with text.
I've rendered and bended TextGeometry but it is difficult to combine these two meshes.
(Аnd yes, I've tried the dynamic textures, this way prohibits the use of own fonts)

[scrinshot of existing model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQi2Q.png)

Perhaps there is another way to draw the text along the path?

Comment: can you provide any example of what you've tried?

Comment: @prisoner849 done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to cover it with text, why not to use textures.

You can set it from a picture with `THREE.TextureLoader()` or you can draw your own on a canvas and apply it to a texture with `var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);`

For exmaple:

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
texture.repeat.set(5, 1);
texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

See the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/82fmu4s7/) example.

There you can uncomment those lines

```
//texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
//texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
```

and see, how the result will change.

UPD. I've updated the fiddle. Used the trick with `WebFontLoader` (from [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31751033/using-local-fonts-in-drawing-html5-canvas-text))

```
WebFontConfig = {
  google: {families: ['Monoton']},
  active: function() {
    init();
    animate();
  },
};

(function(){
  var wf = document.createElement("script");
  wf.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfontloader.js';
  wf.async = 'true';
  document.head.appendChild(wf);
})();
```

Comment: cause in this case I can't use my own font.

Comment: Thanks! Your last update was very useful for me!
But there are some nuances for custom font loading

Comment: glad, that I could help )